# Beginner in d3, making US county map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I've been given an assignment where I need to work with the US map, divided into states and further into counties. I already have the current code and need to extend on it.

I am not able to understand the following snippet from the code.

```
var colorRange = [        'rgb(247,251,255)',
                                    'rgb(222,235,247)',
                                    'rgb(198,219,239)',
                                    'rgb(158,202,225)',
                                    'rgb(107,174,214)',
                                    'rgb(66,146,198)',
                                    'rgb(33,113,181)',
                                    'rgb(8,81,156)',
                                    'rgb(8,48,107)'];

var quantile = d3.scale.quantile()
            .range(colorRange);

var path = d3.geo.path();

var svg = d3.select("#map")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)  
    .append('svg:g')
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
      .append('svg:g');

svg.attr("transform", "scale( " + .9 + ")");

function redraw() {
  console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
      + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

What exactly is happening in each line of this snippet?

Full Code taken from [here](https://github.com/1wheel/deportions/blob/master/index.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `var colorRange` is just a variable holding the colors to be applied to the various counties, the `var quantile` sets the scale for the color to be applied, the `var path` calls the path function and the `var svg` creates an svg. In this the command `.call` has a functionality `.on("zoom"`, which calls the function `redraw`.
`function redraw` defines the function, which translates and scales the svg accordinglly to the zoom

Comment: Zooming is basically through the mouse wheel right? Arent SVG supposed to behave properly on zooming by themselves. Is the function redraw really required?
Also, how are diff colours applied to diff counties? Thanks

Comment: in the snippet the color application is not specified, it should be specified in the path generation of each county. Regarding the redraw, I could be wrong but this function should not only zoom in but also redraw the portion of the map in the svg

Comment: Hi, I've added the link I got the code from. I would like to know, where exactly the color is specified for each county.

Comment: Basically, more importantly, I am interested in showing a bunch of dots in each county, depending on the data i have in my, say an external csv. I can not figure out, where do I inject that information.

Comment: at the end of the code, the function updateMap(key) takes care of changing the colors of the counties, on the .attr("fill" line there's a if function that does that

Comment: you'll need to have the latitude and longitude of the dots you want to apply in the csv and then you can add the csv callback inside the json one

Comment: Anyway of doing it without the long/lat information. What if I have a number say 10, and I want to show 10 dots for that county. and so on, so forth for each county

Comment: you'll need to call the csv then re-enter the json data when generating the circles. If that dataset doesn't need to be dynamic or updated your best choice would be to use topojson command line tool and add that information in the json file

Comment: well, the data is not going to be static or a one time process. So basically, all I want is that, how do I restrict the dots in a particular county. Since all I have is the number of dots and the county, how do I know how to place the dots, only in that particular county? Thanks

Comment: that is not easy at all, I think first off you would need to get the area of each county (doable) and then put the circles inside each county, and I don't really know how you would obtain that easily